# Reinstall SQLAlchemy with speedups after installing compiler

Tags: python, macos, sqlalchemy, clang

I tried to install `sqlalchemy` using `pip3 install sqlalchemy`, but I didn't have `clang` installed so it warned that "speedups are not enabled".  How do I get `clang` on OS X Yosemite and then how do I reinstall `sqlalchemy`?

```
command '/usr/bin/clang' failed with exit status 1
WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Failure information, if any, is above.
Retrying the build without the C extension now.
WARNING: The C extension could not be compiled, speedups are not enabled.
Plain-Python build succeeded.
```

Answer (score 3):

To get clang you need to install XCode from the App Store.

After that you can re-install SQLAlchemy with `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall SQLAlchemy`